# Why is it preferred to have the class of input image as double?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm reading about digital image processing using matlab and there is an example where the input image is to be subjected to some intesity transformations like gamma transformation, contrast stretching, negative etc.

This is the first thing the author does with the image:

```
% If the input is of class double, and it is outside the range
% [0, 1], and the specified transformation is not 'log', convert the
% input to the range [0, 1].
if strcmp(class(f), 'double') & max(f(:)) > 1 & . . .
-strcmp(varargin{1}, 'log')
f = mat2gray(f);
else % Convert to double, regardless of class(f).
f = im2double(f);
```

I'm new to image processing and the thing I don't get is why do all these changes? Why cant we just take the input image as it is ( e.g. `unint16`) and apply the gamma and negative functions to it? Why does it have to be `double` and between `[0 1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many built in functions in Matlab expect the array to be `double` - they may check the data type and fail if it's not. Simple example - if you want the sum of all the pixel values, keeping the data in `uint16` will very quickly result in (possibly silent) overflow. You don't want that to happen.

While `uint16` is a compact format for storing the data, `double` is a better type for performing a wide range of calculations without worrying about these things.

As for converting the image to the range [0, 1] - this means that image representation routines don't need to do further scaling (many routines expect the value to be between 0 - black, and 1 - white (or "fully red, green, blue").

Answer (score 4):

The [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) often keeps both the input and output within the range of [0,1], and the `Vin^gamma = Vout` satisfied this range requirement no matter whether `gamma>1` or `gamma<1`

The double format may be easier for various operations. I don't know the details in the code you provided, but to my experience, sometimes a thresholding method like `a.*(a>100)` will return an error: `Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles` if `a` is `uint16` type. And `uint` format may suffer the problem of overflow.

Comment: Good point about gamma correction. A number in the range [0,1] will still be in that range after this transform. Not true if upper limit is greater than one.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has been stated in other answers, there is a more urgent reason: in Matlab, many operations are **not defined** (1), or **behave differently** (2), on integer types

1. **Not defined**: Try for example this gamma correction: `uint16(100)^2.2`: You will get an error `Integers can only be raised to positive integral powers.` You need to convert to `double` (or `single`) before raising to an arbitrary power.
2. **Behave differently**: Suppose you want to normalize the image `f` to the range [0,1] before the gamma correction. You would do something like `f/intmax('uint16')`. But that will give you only `0` or `1` values! That's because integer division returns an integer (ignoring the remainder), and any value in `f` is less than or equal to `intmax('uint16')`. So you should convert to `double` (or `single`) first to get the expected result (real-number division).

Comment: I am pretty sure we are saying the same thing with different words; I will therefore have to mark this answer as "useful" (given that I think my answer is useful…).

Comment: @Floris Yes, more or less same. I hadn't read you question properly. +1 too